# How to sumif across two tables?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables that I need to do a sumif across. Table 1 contains time periods, i.e. year and quarter at year end (i.e. `4`, `8`, `12` etc.). Table 2 contains the transactions during the year at quarters `3`, `6`, `7` etc.

I need Table 3 to sum all the transactions during the year so that I get the cumulative position at year end.

Here's some sample code to explain what the data looks like and what the output should look like:

```
library(data.table)

x1 <- data.table("Name" = "LOB1", "Year" = 2000, 
                 "Quarter" = c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36))
x2 <- data.table("Name" = "LOB1", "Year" = 2000, 
                 "Quarter" = c(3, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 16, 20, 24), 
                 "Amount" = c(10000, 15000, -2500, 3500, -6500, 25000, 
                              11000, 9000, 7500))
x3 <- data.table("Name" = "LOB1", "Year" = 2000, 
                 "Quarter" = c(4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36), 
                 "Amount" = c(10000, 22500, 19500, 55500, 64500, 72000, 
                              72000, 72000, 72000))
```

I've tried `merge`, `summarise`, `foverlaps` but can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nice question. What basically you are trying to do is to join by `Name`, `Year` and `Quarter <= Quarter`, while summing all the matched `Amount` values. This is both possible using the new non-equi joins (which were introduced in the latest stable version of data.table v-1.10.0) and `foverlaps` (while the latter will be probably sub-optimal)

**Non-Equi joins:**

```
x2[x1, # for each value in `x1` find all the matching values in `x2`
   .(Amount = sum(Amount)), # Sum all the matching values in `Amount`
   on = .(Name, Year, Quarter <= Quarter), # join conditions
   by = .EACHI] # Do the summing per each match in `i`
#    Name Year Quarter Amount
# 1: LOB1 2000       4  10000
# 2: LOB1 2000       8  22500
# 3: LOB1 2000      12  19500
# 4: LOB1 2000      16  55500
# 5: LOB1 2000      20  64500
# 6: LOB1 2000      24  72000
# 7: LOB1 2000      28  72000
# 8: LOB1 2000      32  72000
# 9: LOB1 2000      36  72000
```

---

As a side note, you can easily add `Amount` in place in `x1` (proposed by @Frank):

```
x1[, Amount := 
  x2[x1, sum(x.Amount), on = .(Name, Year, Quarter <= Quarter), by = .EACHI]$V1
]
```

This might be convenient if you have more than just the three join columns in that table.

---

**foverlaps:**

You mentioned `foverlaps`, so in theory you could achieve the same using this function too. Though I'm afraid you will easily get out of memory. Using `foverlaps`, you will need to create a huge table where each value in `x2` joined multiple times to each value in `x1` and store everything in memory

```
x1[, Start := 0] # Make sure that we always join starting from Q0
x2[, Start := Quarter] # In x2 we want to join all possible rows each time 
setkey(x2, Name, Year, Start, Quarter) # set keys
## Make a huge cartesian join by overlaps and then aggregate
foverlaps(x1, x2)[, .(Amount = sum(Amount)), by = .(Name, Year, Quarter = i.Quarter)]
#    Name Year Quarter Amount
# 1: LOB1 2000       4  10000
# 2: LOB1 2000       8  22500
# 3: LOB1 2000      12  19500
# 4: LOB1 2000      16  55500
# 5: LOB1 2000      20  64500
# 6: LOB1 2000      24  72000
# 7: LOB1 2000      28  72000
# 8: LOB1 2000      32  72000
# 9: LOB1 2000      36  72000
```

Comment: Thanks so much - I just got this working. Very much appreciated! It looks like both of my tables need to have the same columns in them. If x2 had one additional column that I didn't want included in the resulting table x3 , would the code be the same?

Comment: You can specify in the `on` argument what ever column names you want from both tables. For instance `.on(column1 = column2, column3 = column4)`, etc. The LHS of the suasion are columns from `x1` while the RHS of the equation are columns from `x2`.